# PG_bulkload utility postgresql need help

Tags: postgresql, import, export

i am using `COPY` command to export the data to the out file with changes made to the data before export using option `ST_asBinary()` using command

```
COPY (
    SELECT st_asBinary(geom) FROM n_america
) TO '/install/shp_data/n_america_asbin_1_col.txt' 
WITH DELIMITER ',';
```

now i am facing problem with Restoring back to the other table with geometry column , which is now converted to binary while exporting

i have tried with `COPY FROM` as well as `PG_BULKLOAD` utility , but i did't got any solution to do this ,

any one please help

Regards
Deepak M

Answer (score 2):

Your simple solution is to import into a separate table and then use another query to copy the data back, converting to proper format.